# Woocommerce add fee if cart contains items from both categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have this code where I am trying to check if the cart contains products from BOTH categories; **Drinks** AND **Bundles**. If true, then apply the fee of -1.

Currently it is working, but not quite correctly as it is checking whether the cart contains EITHER **Drinks** OR **Bundles**.

I need it to check that **both** of the categories are in the cart, not just one. I am sure it is something simple I am missing?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_pcat_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_pcat_fee( $cart ) {
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

// Categories in a coma separated array
$categories = array('drinks','bundles');
$fee_amount = 0;

// Loop through cart items
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) )
        $fee_amount = -1;
}

// Adding the fee
if ( $fee_amount < 0 ){
    // Last argument is related to enable tax (true or false)
    WC()->cart->add_fee( __( "Kombucha Bundle Discount", "woocommerce" ), $fee_amount, false );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the loop of `$cart->get_cart()` get category using `get_the_terms()` and push to an array then you can loop `$must_categories` to check both category are available or not.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_pcat_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_pcat_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Categories in a coma separated array
    $must_categories = array('drinks','bundles');
    $fee_amount = 0;

    $product_cat = array();

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
           $product_cat[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
    
    array_unique( $product_cat );
    
    foreach ( $must_categories as $key => $must_cat ) {
        
        if( in_array($must_cat, $product_cat) ){
            $fee_amount = -1;
        }else{
            $fee_amount = 0;
            break;
        }

    }

    // Adding the fee
    if ( $fee_amount < 0 ){
        // Last argument is related to enable tax (true or false)
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __( "Kombucha Bundle Discount", "woocommerce" ), $fee_amount, false );
    }
}
```

**Tested and works**

Comment: I have tried your code and changed the categories array, but now it does not seem to trigger at all?

Comment: can you share the site link? I have tested in my local and working fine.

Comment: Both categories need to be in 1 product or either both be available in the cart?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.